# MS Access split form datasheet totals

Tags: ms-access

I have a split form in MS Access which has columns that I need a total on at the bottom of the datasheet.  I can get a totals row to appear at the bottom.  However, it appears that each time I enter the form, I will need to select the "type" of total that I want.  Type being count, sum, ect.  For the columns that I want a total on, I will always want a sum.  There are approximately 15 columns on the datasheet with approximately 10 of those needed to be summed.  Therefore, users are going to be unhappy if they have to choose sum for each of those columns each time.  Is there anyway that I can set the columns that need to be totaled and the type when the form is loaded.  The totals will need to change if the user filters the form.
Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

If you view the form in **Form View**, add the appropriate totals, and then **save the form whilst still in Form View** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), the totals should be retained the next time you open the form.